# Can I overload the "view" function in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to have a template view that is always called and I think overloading the view function is probably the best way. Anyone know anything about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to read the following article on creating/overriding core classes and functions. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: No problem. It's a very useful aspect of CI, and is one of their key selling points because it allows you to upgrade later with relatively little pain!